# GitHub Actions: Get all job commands to run in a Docker container

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

For GitHub Actions, I'd like to run all commands for a job in a Docker container, but am having trouble getting this to work. Here's the code for my action:

```
name: PR Checks

on: [push]

jobs:
  my_checks:
    container: 
      image: docker://alpine:latest
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: uname -a
      - run: cat /proc/version
```

The output of it indicates that the commands are running on the host Ubuntu rather than the Alpine Linux. Here's the output that indicates it:

[image]

How do I get these commands to run inside the `container:` image?

(As an aside, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930529/github-action-how-do-i-run-commands-inside-a-docker-container), but the answer doesn't work)

Comment: Since Docker containers share the host kernel, commands like `uname` that print kernel-level details don't say anything about whether you're running inside a container or not.  You could prove this one way or another by trying to run a command that an Ubuntu system will have but an Alpine image won't, like `bash`.

Comment: They are already running inside the container. Furthermore, Ubuntu uses `apt-get` to manage packages whereas alpine linux uses `apk`. Easy test could be to run `apk update` and if it is successful, then you are definitely running on the container. Also there is no need to specify the `runs-on` option if you specify `container`, this is also another way to check

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze and @smac89 ! Your comments helped -- things are running in the container. I just wanted to note though that `runs-on` is required despite having `container`. GitHub will flag it as an invalid workflow file without it.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do same thing. but for me it seems like not running in container. I am running Django test cases. Added container and services. any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See comments on question. Answer is in there. The code sample in the question does run commands in the container. Thanks to @DavidMaze and @smac89!)